# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (595, 10083)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, neural-network

I was trying to build a CNN model using Keras. Here is my code:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
                  ...

# Define x_train...data
x_data=df.iloc[:,1:10084].values-25 
# x_data = np.array(x_data).tolist()  
y_data=df[['type1','type2']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_data,test_size=0.2)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=100,
          epochs=100,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[history])
```

It returned the error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (595, 10083)

After referring to other questions I tried to reshape the dimension of the data array using

```
X_train = X_train[np.newaxis, :, :, :]
```

which changed it to 3-dimentional and returned the error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 595, 10083)

How should I increase the dimension of the data to 4?

Comment: What data is this?

Comment: There are too much details which may not fit in the comment, please see [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/62747/83084) for the data

Comment: Why not use an RNN? If you want a CNN, you need a *1D* CNN here.

Comment: thanks @gmds It performed badly on my data as I joint various features of time series form into one so I'd like to see how it goes on `CNN`

Comment: @gmds I changed `Conv2D` to `Conv1D` and had this `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (744, 10183, 1) but got array with shape (595, 10083, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first layer of the model, which a 2D convolution, is expecting (I believe) 2D image data with multiple channels.  Something like:

(img_height, img_width, num_channels).

In addition, you need to have another dimension for the "batch" or "sample."  Therefore the final shape will be:

(num_samples, img_height, img_width, num_channels).

So, you'll need to reshape your input data to be in the above pattern, with the various dimensions having the interpretation I've indicated, based on what I infer from your code.

You might look at functions like np.reshape and np.expand_dims, depending on how your input data is formatted in the first place.

You can create some test data like this:

```
x_train = np.random.random((4,32,32,3))

# then try out the model prediction

model.predict(x_train)
```

which is four images of 32x32 size, and 3 channels, to verify your processing.

You'll also need to create something appropriate for the y_train when you do the actual fitting.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ad2004 I'm not using image data- is it correct to use 2D convolution? How can I change the data shape to `(num_samples, img_height, img_width, num_channels)`?Are there limitations in doing this or can I simply assign random numbers in `[a,b, c, d]` format? What are `num_samples ` and `num_channels` in temperate data for example? Sorry I have too many questions

Comment: @nilsinelabore .  The model you use needs to be consistent with the type of data you are working with.  If the "model" which is already defined in your code is designed to work with image data, then it might not be appropriate for your case.  You might want to explore examples that relevant to 1D data/timeseries - there are some examples in the Keras documentation:  https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/ among other places.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes agreed. The data involves combining multiple time series features into one. I used `RNN` thinking it is like a time series but didn't perform well due to the great disparity in the various features. Hence I'm trying `CNN`. Thank you so much